# I am not able to find Recruiting App

Tags: custom

I was installed Recruiting App and installation Mail also came.  But not able to find in "**Recruiting App**" in *AppLauncher*.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably an issue with permissions. Some installable apps include a permission set that you can assign you yourself. So:

1. Check if you have a profile or permission set assigned that gives you access to the app. Per your question, you shouldn't have one.
2. If not, look if the package that you installed includes a permission set and assign it to yourself.
3. If not, create a profile / permission set that gives you access to the app
   and assign it to yourself.